# Logout of Chrome Custom Tabs using Facebook SDK 4.14

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome

I have integrated Facebook SDK to my android application using the following [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android). One of the feature is using the Chrome Custom Tabs. I have implemented the method but now I am having a problem with logging out of the Chrome Custom Tabs. 
When logging in the first time the chrome tab askes for the user credential. After the first time the credentials are save and only approval is required to log in again. After logging out of Facebook in my application `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` trying to login again will open the approval page again without the option to log in using different user credentials.

Is there a way to programmatically log out (clear Session) from the Chrome custom tab?

Comment: I don't think so. The user should manually log out from Chrome.

Comment: I face the same issue as you. Now I want to log in with different Facebook account but cannot sign out from previous logged in account in Chrome Custom Tabs.

Comment: i have same issue, i did search many hours for that and only solution work `LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_VIEW_ONLY)`, but you can't login via fb app, fb lite anymore